# Absolute position and overflow property

Tags: html, css, css-position

I an making this page, which have a sticky footer.

The content div, is going through the sticky footer, and because of the absolute positioning I cant make `overflow:hidden;` work properly.

Can anyone help me ?

Please no comments on the design :P not my cup of tea either.

[Link to site](http://www.thomasteilmann.dk/powerdisco) | [Link to jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ENXw5)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clicking on a random link from an unknown website. Could you provide more details, or replicate the problem on a http://jsfiddle.com?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that might help helping you. http://jsfiddle.net/ENXw5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to the footer

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%
```

Comment: It kinda works, but it still scrolls. The content div is still way to high, i think.. dunno if its just me

Answer (score 0):

First, put your `#footer` in your `#wrapper`.

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#main {
   z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution, but it didnt work for me. If you look at the page again, i have made the changes. Thx for reply